# Can a string be constructed in reverse with the reverse iterators?

Tags: c++

I tried using the iterator constructor of `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string reverse_string(std::string str) {
  return std::string(str.rend(), str.rbegin());
}
```

But when calling this function, I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

Comment: `rbegin()` and `rend()` are exactly like `begin()` and `end()` - `rbegin()` is the start of range and `rend()` is the end of range. You need to reverse the arguments.

Comment: The words "begin" and "end" in "rbegin" and "rend" do not refer to the original sequence but to its (conceptual) reversal; `rbegin` is the first element if you traverse the original string backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can but you've swapped the iterators:

```cpp
std::string reverse_string(std::string str) {
    return std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
//                         ^^^^^^        ^^^^
}
```

`rbegin()` returns an iterator pointing at the *end* of the string and when increasing this iterator, it actually goes backwards in the string, until it meets `rend()` which points at the beginning of the string.

Compare with:

```cpp
void print_in_reverse(std::string str) {
    for(auto it = str.rbegin(), end = str.rend(); it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried seeing what each iterator dereferences to and I guess I didn't notice that `rbegin()` got me the last char of the string…

Comment: @Nowhereman Easy mistake to make! Glad it worked out!